# definition of function in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, geometry

what is the definition of function in polar coordinates? and the definition of injetive and surjective function in polar coordinates? I don´t know if there is a definition of function in polar coordinates but if there is one I would like you to tell me

Comment: The definition of function is relevant to coordinate, instead depends on topology on which function is defined.

Comment: A function is a function. Choice of coordinates only influences the picture you draw.

Answer (score 1):

A function is a rule which assigns each element in some set (the domain) to a single element of another set (the codomain).

We can think of coordinates as names of points.  A choice of Cartesian or polar coordinates is just a choice of naming convention.  The point which lies one unit above the origin can be called "$(0,1)$" (Cartesian) or "$(1, \pi/2)$" (polar).

But the definition of function doesn't change.  Neither does the definition of injective or surjective.  The property of being injective or surjective (or a function) is a property of a particular rule, not of the naming system.